# Next.js: Distincting if user is trying to access page from URL or by routing in app

Tags: next.js

I have this little problem.
We have an app that should do the following:

user tries to enter route `/` by URL -> he's redirected to `/abc`

user tries to enter route `/` by routing made in app -> `/` page is rendered.

I don't know how to distinct when it's being redirected by router and not url.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be passing a param.
This is how [router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush) works:

```
router.push(url, as, options)
```

`as` allows to pass params which do not show up in the address bar. So you can do something like:

```
router.push('/?internal=true', 'internal');
```

And in your [`middleware.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) directly redirect:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const middleware = (req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const pathname = nextUrl.pathname;
 if (pathname === '/') { 
    return NextResponse.redirect('/abc');
    }
}
```

Or in your component read the query params from the [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) and act accordingly:

```
  const { query } = useRouter()
  //if condition using query
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using next.js version 10

Comment: Then i guess you will have to do without middleware. Either do it in getServerSideProps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65784602/next-js-getserversideprops-redirection-err-http-headers-sent-error or in the component as described above

Comment: I came across ctx.req (inside _app.tsx in getInitialProps). It works properly. ctx.req -> when from url !ctx.req -> when from routing. Do you think this is passable solution?

Comment: Yes in `getServerSideProps` there is a context object which has a key called `req`. You can extract query from there, and then redirect based on some checked. For redirect just return an object with `redirect` key