# Use router from getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

What I want to achieve is to redirect the user to the login page if his token has been expired.

Inside `getServerSideProps`, I send a get request to the server to receive some data; if I get the data I want to provide this data as props for my page but if it's unauthorized, I want to redirect the user to the login page, but it seems that I can't call `useRouter` inside `getServerSideProps` when I try I get this error:

> React Hook "useRouter" is called in function "getServerSideProps" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".eslint

This is my code

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, params }) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  const userId = params.userId;
  const router = useRouter(); // the line with the error
  let result = {};

   await axiosPrivateWithToken(accessToken)
    .get(`/user/${userId}`)
    .then((res) => {
      result = res.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if(error.response.status == 401) {
      here where I want to use router.push('/login')
     }
    });

}
```

Is it possible? If so - how? Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js getServerSideProps redirection ERR\_HTTP\_HEADERS\_SENT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65784602/next-js-getserversideprops-redirection-err-http-headers-sent-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only call `hooks` from `function component` or a `custom React hook function` as it is mentioned in the error, therefore there is no way to use `useRouter` from inside `getServerSidePros`.

**However** you can achieve this by the `redirect` key object

```
 .then((res) => {
      result = res.data;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      if(error.response.status == 401) result = 'redirection'
  });
```

then based on the value of `result` you decide what to do :

```
if(result === 'redirection') {
return {
 redirect: {
   destination: "/login",
   permanent: false,
 }};
}else {
// what you are used to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use `useRouter` inside `getServerSideProps`.
Instead, you can return `axiosPrivateWithToken` response and receive it as props on your component and put it inside useEffect and handle your redirection logic there.

Comment: Redirecting client side would be unnecessary and bad ux. You can redirect server side with `context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/login" })`.

Answer (score 0):

We can direct users to the login page if "axiosPrivateWithToken" fails.

```
export async function authenticatedUsers(userId) {
  try {
    const response = await axiosPrivateWithToken(accessToken).get(`/user/${userId}`)
    const result = response.data;

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
  return false;
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({req, params}) => {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  const userId = params.userId;

  let result = await authenticatedUsers(userId);

  if (result == null) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/login',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
        result
    }
  };
};
```