# Nextjs Warning: Cannot update a component (`Router`) while rendering a different component (`Home`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Home`

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am using firebase as backend for in my Next.js project. While using Routing I get some errors:

My Code:

```js
"use client";
import { useAuthContext } from "@/context/AuthContext";
import Login from "./login/Loginpage";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const { user } = useAuthContext();
  const router = useRouter();

  const data = user == null ? <Login /> : router.push("../admin");
  return <>{data}</>;
}
```

Everything works well but I get following errors in console.

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Router`) while rendering a different component (`Home`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Home`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
    at Home (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/app/adminLogin/page.js:20:91)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:59:11)
```

I tried a lot to fix it
Below code does not give any error but the DOM is loaded before routing

```js
'use client'
import React from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "@/context/AuthContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Login from "./login/Loginpage";
function Page() {
    const { user } = useAuthContext()
    const router = useRouter()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (user == null) router.push("../admin")
    }, [user])

    return (<><Login/></>);
}

export default Page;
```

Is there any way to route before the DOM is loaded OR  Is there any way to resolve the error in first code?

Comment: you can use getServerSideProps redirect as in here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/65785699/13441937 )

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional rendering to make sure that components render only if the condition is true

```
return (
<>{user && <Login />}</>
)
```